# Why does Random.Next() return an int instead of uint?

Tags: c#, .net, random

According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the method `Random.Next()` **Returns a nonnegative random number.** Why on earth does it return `int` instead of `uint`?

It seems that returning a value that would be evenly distributed over the range of the type used would make the most sense.  From a usage standpoint - if you are using `int` it should cover the range of `int`, and if you are using `uint` it should also return an even distribution over the type.  Isn't that the point of using a type?

Comment: Only two of the three overloads return positive numbers.  The overload that takes a minimum can return negative numbers.

Comment: There's little to be gained in asking why the designers did things this way. If you want a random uint, then multiply `Random.NextDouble()` by `uint.MaxValue`.

Comment: In addition, the most common usage is getting a random value such that 0 <= value <= N, where N is some user-specified value. It's likely that the API designers made it easier for the most common usage, and allowed for negative numbers with an overload that lets you specify the range.

Comment: @Servy I don't think the `+ (uint)int.MaxValue` is nessesary, any negative value will cast to it's twos complement value when you cast to `uint`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yep.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

uint is not CLS-Compliant.

Here is some great reading on the topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This raises the question on why `uint` is not CLS compliant.

Comment: Because, at least at the time the CLS was written, not all .NET languages supported unsigned types.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That's pretty much just begging the question...again.

Comment: @Servy: I dunno, answers it pretty well for me: "VB is a bad language, CLS suffered to cater to its users."

Comment: And there are a number of routines in the [BCL which use unsigned types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4.aspx), they are however marked as `[CLSComplaint(false)]`.

Comment: @user7116 It begs the question as it merely prompts the question of "Why don't the other .NET languages support unsigned types?"  It's an answer that doesn't actually give anyone useful information, merely the need to rephrase their question.

Comment: @Servy: by that logic we should ask why there are even unsigned types to start with, etc ad nauseam. It really doesn't beg anything more than any other question.

Comment: @user7116 Thank you for that tidbit of information regarding BCL.

Comment: @baultista, thanks for the info!  Makes sense, given that the BCL was designed for various languages.  Its interesting the weird quirks that that causes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to why MSFT did it that way.
But if you want random UInt32 it is easy enough.

```
Random ran = new Random();
Debug.WriteLine(Int32.MaxValue.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(((UInt32)ran.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)).ToString());
```